# StartActivity in fragment with data binding

Tags: android, android-intent

Creating a viewModel which data binding in fragment, setup a liveData in this viewModel and observe this liveData to startActivity in fragment.

```
class MyFragment : Fragment() {

    ...

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater,
            R.layout.fragment_my, container, false)

        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(MyViewModel::class.java)

        binding.myViewModel = viewModel

        binding.apply {
            myViewModel.myLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { ResponseData ->
                if (ResponseData...) {
                    val intent = Intent(this, OtherActivity::class.java)
                    startActivity(intent)
                }
            })
        }

        return binding.root
    }
}
```

But the intent init false seems not get the context of the fragment.

Comment: have you tried  val intent = Intent(getActivity(), OtherActivity::class.java)
                    startActivity(intent)

Comment: context should be of activity in which fragment is placed

Comment: The compiler replace it with `val intent = Intent(activity, OtherActivity::class.java)`

Comment: yes it should be activity. I got mixed in java and kotlin. What error you get if you use activity?

Comment: use `val intent = Intent(context, OtherActivity::class.java)`